# How to work around header not found in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
#include "missing.h"
```

I have a library that have missing.h header file which in Full version of the framework I include that library but in lite version I don't want to link that library..

But in objective c when you include missing file it will not continue building it will show an errors that the header "missing.h" is not found.

How can I work around this problem? like to say if the header not found don't include it at all

Comment: You cannot.  It's a fatal error.

Comment: How do you switch between "lite" and "full" version? Different targets?

Comment: Yes I made different target for each version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use preprocessor directives.

```
#if FULL_VERSION
#include "missing.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks I will try with your suggestion

Comment: I tried it .. yes it works fine thanks .. but like what @DuncanC said I need to remove the library from being linked .. and I can't figured out how to do that in a dynamic way .. like depending on configuration file or something!

Comment: You can set up a second **target** in your project's configuration. In the second target, simply remove the link.

Comment: Yes but it will make the structure a little bit complicated like I will have a lot of targets and when trying to build it shows me a lot of build errors while there is no ordering for dependencies until getting it correctly..
I don't know some one suggest me to see **cmake** .. I don't know if it will help me
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why would you have a lot of targets? There's one for full and one for lite.

Answer (score 0):

Ian's answer is good if you really need to not include the header.

Note that #importing the header does not mean that the binary for the library is included in your project, and conversely, not importing the header does not prevent the library's binary from being linked into your project.

The more important thing is changing the build phases step of your "lite" target so it doesn't copy the library into your "lite" application.

Comment: From build phase I am linking the binaries of my libraries to the main framework static library.. 
Thanks it is really important point